# Let n be an odd positive number. Prove that n | $(2^{n!}-1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let n be an odd positive number. Prove that n | $(2^{n!}-1)$. 
I don't know how to start this. If n is prime I might try Fermat's Little Theorem or something but as n is merely odd I don't know what to do.

Comment: There's a generalization of FLT, that uses the Euler's function. It may prove useful in this case

Comment: Thank you! @rtybase I believe these two questions are related. However I cannot seem to develop a proof for the case n as the link shows (n+1)(n-1)

Comment: @RnHdw you will need to go through all the details, 6 minutes may not be enough. But the main takeaway is $\varphi(m)<m$.

Comment: @RnHdw also see Gone's answer ...

Comment: And see **Step 2** in N.S. answer.

Comment: @RnHdw it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let $\phi(n)$ be the Euler totient function. Since $\phi(n) \leq n$ we have $\phi(n)|n!$.