# Prove that $n|2^{(n-1)!}-1$ for any $n = 2k + 1$ given $k$ is a natural number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What i have done so for:

1. $2^{(n-1)!} \equiv 1 (mod\hspace 1 mmn)$
2. Thought about wilson`s theorem but $n$ is not a prime.
3. Tried to break the factorial and reduce the congruence to $2^{(n-2)!}$ but not sure this is the right way to do.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If $n=2k+1$ then $n$ and $2$ are relatively prime.  So $2^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Comment: @Mabadai FYI, by using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%20%5Cmid%202%5E%7B(n-1)!%7D-1%24&p=1), I was able to find the very similar [Let n be an odd positive number. Prove that n | $(2^{n!}-1)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3678004/602049).

Comment: @fleablood Are $n$ and $2$ relatively prime because of Euclid`s Division Theorem?

Comment: Thanks @JohnOmielan i found the linked question more useful [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126531/prove-that-for-any-even-positive-integer-n-n2-1-mid-2n-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, then surely $(2,n)=1$. So you can use Fermat's Little Theorem(Euler's Generalization).

And also, $\phi(n)<n$ holds, so $\phi(n)\mid(n-1)!$.

Let $(n-1)!=m\phi(n)$, then $2^{(n-1)!}=2^{m\phi(n)}=(2^{\phi(n)})^m\equiv1^m=1\pmod n$.

Comment: Nitpick.... FLT is when $n$ is prime.  Euler's Theorem is for relatively prime moduli.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood. I learned this theorem as Euler's generalization of FLT, so I confused.

Comment: Oh... I never thought of it like that.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi(n)=\left|\left(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}\right)^×\right|$, divides $(n-1)!$, and $2\in \left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^×$, because $n$ is odd. Finish using Euler's Thm. [Mistakenly called it Fermat, thanks @fleablood in the comments for the correction]